# Why ionic polarizability is temperature independent?

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, polarization, dielectric

Why is ionic polarizability temperature independent? According to me, as we increase the temperature ions should start oscillating and an ionic polarizability should change. Can we see this through by using statistical mechanics or any kind of Mathematics that ionic polarizability should be temperature independent? As for magnetic dipoles we can derive and see the magnetic dipole moment is inversely dependent on the temperature (the statistics of paramagnetism).

Comment: This is likely due to non-linear effects. It could be helpful, if you provide a basic model for what you are talking about.

Comment: Actually, when was studying about ionic polarizability while reading about dielectric material. I came to know that ionic polarizability is temperature independent. I couldn't find a suitable answer why this happens. Ionic polarizability should depends on temperature. Because as we increase the temperature ions starts oscillating and ionic polarizability should be temperature dependent.

Comment: On the internet it was written that displacement of ions is temperature independent. But I'm not able to see why ?

Comment: It is not clear what your background is and what kind of explanation you expect. E.g., in case of magnetic or electric dipoles one can simply derive the temperature dependence from the potential energy and Boltzmann distribution: $U(\theta)=-mB\cos\theta$, $P(\theta)\propto e^{-U(\theta)/(k_BT)}$.

Comment: I totally agree. But i wanna know why ionic polarizability is temperature independent. ? What makes it temperature independent. And how we can statistically see that temperature doesn't changes the value of ionic polarizability.